# How to center in CSS only after specific HTML element?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to move to new line and center only `a` in last `li`. Everything I tried was changing also previous anchors. I can't touch markup, only CSS. Anyone good in CSS know how to target only that last `a`?

The code is:

```css
ol{
  list-style:none;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
ol li{
  padding:5px;
  margin:1px;
  background:#e6e6fa;
}
.classX{
  text-align:center;
}
.classX a{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:.3em .5em;
  margin:0 auto;
  color:#000;
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
time,
time + p{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:.8em;
}
span + a{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:.3em .5em;
  color:#000;
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ol>
    <li><!-- This link contain 'a' in first 'p' -->
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      <p>Primary description with
        <a href="finally-styled.html">link</a>
        inside</p>
    </li>
    <li class="classX"><!-- The most imptnt here is to center 'a' -->
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      <p>Some related content, is centered.</p>
      <a href="one.html">One</a>
      <a href="second.html">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li><!-- The most imptnt here is to center 'a' -->
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      <p>Primary description.</p>
      <time>2038-01-19</time>
      <p>Category</p>
      <span><!-- Invisible element, yeah I know. But might help to target the 'a'. --></span>
      <a href="this-1-should-be-centered.html">Link</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Could you please show us at least your code and what have you done so far so we may be able to help you.

Comment: Please provide your HTML structure. If the code following the `a` tag is not contained within another tag, this is not going to be possible with CSS alone.

Comment: And I want a million dollars.. ;) - Chandler

Comment: at a guess you'd wrap the latter part in a div or span and style it `"text-align:center"`. sounds very simple to me.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifyable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code, updated my question. *What a shame, I never thought that any of my questions will be downvoted so many times. Sorry for that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, answer was simple, all I had to do was to add one pseudo-class.

```css
ol{
  list-style:none;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
ol li{
  padding:5px;
  margin:1px;
  background:#e6e6fa;
}
.classX{
  text-align:center;
}
.classX a{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:.3em .5em;
  margin:0 auto;
  color:#000;
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
time,
time + p{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:.8em;
}
span + a{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:.3em .5em;
  color:#000;
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
ol li:nth-last-of-type(1) a{
 display:block;
 max-width:3em;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ol>
    <li><!-- This link contain 'a' in first 'p' -->
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      <p>Primary description with
        <a href="finally-styled.html">link</a>
        inside</p>
    </li>
    <li class="classX"><!-- The most imptnt here is to center 'a' -->
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      <p>Some related content, is centered.</p>
      <a href="one.html">One</a>
      <a href="second.html">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li><!-- The most imptnt here is to center 'a' -->
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      <p>Primary description.</p>
      <time>2038-01-19</time>
      <p>Category</p>
      <span><!-- Invisible element, yeah I know. But might help to target the 'a'. --></span>
      <a href="this-1-should-be-centered.html">Link</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it, contain all the stuff you want centered in a div.

```
//Beginning of the page here
<a></a>
<div class="centered">
   //Rest of the page's content here
</div>
```

And the css:

```
div.centered{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add more `<div>` tags inside your main `<div>` tag somewhat like following.

```
<div>
<div style="text-align:left;">
this text is left aligned
</div>
<a href="#">this is link</a>
<div style="text-align:center">This text is center aligned</div>
</div>
```

and correct me if i misunderstood your question